# Pandas DataFrame splitting with multiple attributes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

If I had a pandas data frame with columns x , y , h , w and label.

For example:

```
x  y  h  w  label
0  0  4  4  1
4  0  4  8  1
0  4  8  4  2
8  0  4  4  3
8  8  4  8  2
```

Is there any way to split them into groups with same h and w values?

Into following

Group 1

```
x  y  h  w  label
0  0  4  4  1
8  0  4  4  3
```

Group 2

```
x  y  h  w  label
4  0  4  8  1
8  8  4  8  2
```

Group3

```
x  y  h  w  label
0  4  8  4  2
```

Comment: Please provide an actual sample of your dataframe and a sample of your expected output.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`DataFrame.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) + `dict comprehension` to get a dict of DataFrame, you could create new variables with [`globals()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#globals) but it is not recommended

```
dict_dfs = {i:group for i, group in df.groupby(['h', 'w'])}
```

Or

```
dict_dfs = {f'Group {i}' : group 
            for i, (_, group) in enumerate(df.groupby(['h', 'w']), 1)}
```